# What's going on with jQuery extend function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm adding a photo gallery to my website and I have it all working, but I'm curious as to what's going on in some of the JS

```
(function($){

  $.fn.extend({

    simpleGal: function (options) {

      var defaults = {
        mainImage: ".placeholder"
      };

      options = $.extend(defaults, options);

      return this.each(function () {

        var thumbnail = $(this).find("a"),
            mainImage = $(this).siblings().find(options.mainImage);

        thumbnail.on("click", function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var galleryImage = $(this).attr("href");
          mainImage.attr("src", galleryImage);
        });

      });

    }

  });

})(jQuery);
```

What's going on with the $.fn.extend? and defaults? I get everything after var thumbnail, but I'm slightly confused as to what's going on in the first half.

Comment: It's an object oriented construct, check docs: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/

Answer (score 0):

$.fn.extend merges the two objects together into the first one

[see refrence](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/)

Here defualt options will be extended with the custom options provided by the user of the module

Answer (score 0):

The [`$.fn.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.fn.extend/) function, from the docs:

> extends the jQuery prototype ($.fn) object to provide new methods that can be  chained to the jQuery() function.

So it allows you to add functionality to the jQuery object. Here the function `simpleGal` is being added.

The `defaults` specifies default values for parameters passed into the function. The defaults are then merged using [`extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) - any default values will be overwritten by values passed in. This is useful for complex functions which have many possible parameters and replaces code such as:

```
param1 = (typeof param1 !== 'undefined') ? param1 : 'default-val';
```